# Merge two objects without override

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, merge

I have a defaultObject like that:

```
var default = {
    abc: "123",
    def: "456",
    ghi: {
       jkl: "789",
       mno: "012"
    }
};
```

And I have another like:

```
var values = {
    abc: "zzz",
    ghi: {
       jkl: "yyy",
    }
};
```

How can I merge those 2 objects with the following result (no override)?

```
var values = {
    abc: "zzz",
    def: "456",
    ghi: {
       jkl: "yyy",
       mno: "012"
    }
};
```

(I don't want to change the default object!)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With ES2015 now being supported in all modern browsers, the native `Object.assign` can be used to extend objects

```
Object.assign({}, _default, values)
```

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Note that `default` is a reserved keyword, and can't be used as a variable name

---

The original answer, written in 2013 :

Since this is tagged with jQuery, you could use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for a simple cross-browser solution

```
var temp = {};
$.extend(true, temp, _default, values);
values = temp;
```

---

Comment: But this will change my default 'default_array' and I don't want it, because it is a global variable...

Comment: @amp - that's easily avoided by using a temporary object.

Comment: This doesn't work, `ghi` will be overwritten, not merged together.

Comment: yes, existing objects are being removed inside nested json

Answer (score 17):

For those who don't use jQuery, here comes a vanilla-js solution.

**Solution**:

```
function extend (target) {
    for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
        var from = arguments[i];
        if(typeof from !== 'object') continue;
        for(var j in from) {
            if(from.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                target[j] = typeof from[j]==='object'
                ? extend({}, target[j], from[j])
                : from[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

**Compressed** (with [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com)):

Only 199 characters!

```
var extend=function e(c){for(var d=1;d<arguments.length;++d){var a=arguments[d];if("object"===typeof a)for(var b in a)a.hasOwnProperty(b)&&(c[b]="object"===typeof a[b]?e({},c[b],a[b]):a[b])}return c}
```

**How to use**:

```
extend(target, obj1, obj2); // returns target
```

If you only want to merge, use

```
var merged = extend({}, obj1, obj2);
```

**Features**:

- It doesn't look at objects' prototype.
- Ignores non-objects.
- It is recursive in order to merge properties which are objects.
- Objects referenced in `target`'s properties, if extended,  are replaced by new ones, and the original ones are not modified.
- In case of same property names, the merged value will be the merging of the objects after the last (in the order of arguments) non-object value. Or, if the last isn't an object, itself.

**Examples**:

```
extend({}, {a:1}, {a:2});            // {a:2}
extend({}, {a:1}, {b:2});            // {a:1, b:2}
extend({}, {a: {b:1}}, {a: {b:2}});  // {a: {b:2}}
extend({}, {a: {b:1}}, {a: {c:2}});  // {a: {b:2, c:2}}
extend({}, {a: {a:1}}, {a: {b:2}}, {a: 'whatever non object'});
    // {a: "whatever non object"}
extend({}, {a: {a:1}}, {a: {b:2}}, {a: 'whatever non object'}, {a: {c:3}},{a: {d:4}});
    // {a: {c:3, d:4}}
```

**Warning**:

Be aware that if browser is not clever enough, it could be trapped in an infinite loop:

```
var obj1={},
    obj2={};
obj1.me=obj1;
obj2.me=obj2;
extend({},obj1,obj2);
```

If the browser is clever enough, it can throw an error, or return `{me: undefined}`, or whatever.

Note that this warning also applies if you use jQuery's `$.extend`.

Comment: One problem. It converts arrays to objects.

Answer (score 8):

Also if you are happy with ES6:

```
Object.assign({}, default, values)
```

Comment: Still overrides if value exist in default

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to simply extend value by default (instead of the other way around which would override default)

```
Object.assign(value, default) // values of default overrides value
default = value // reset default to value
```

The caveat here is that the content of value is changed as well. Upside is no library is required and easier than the plain vanilla solution above.

Answer (score 3):

My version based on Oriol's answer adds a check for arrays, so that arrays don't get transformed into funny {'0': ..., '1': ...} thingys

```
function extend (target) {
  for(var i=1; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
    var from = arguments[i];
    if(typeof from !== 'object') continue;
    for(var j in from) {
      if(from.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
        target[j] = typeof from[j]==='object' && !Array.isArray(from[j])
          ? extend({}, target[j], from[j])
          : from[j];
      }
    }
  }
  return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the easiest way to to this is to use `mergeWith()` from lodash ( https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith ) which accepts a customizer function that decides what to do with every property merge. Here is one that is recursive :

```
const mergeFunction = (objValue, srcValue) => {
  if (typeof srcValue === 'object') {
    _.mergeWith(objValue, srcValue, mergeFunction)
  } else if (objValue) {
    return objValue
  } else {
    return srcValue
  }
}
```