# How do I create a new Object that has 2 or more Objects' properties that have different sizes and set up a new property

Tags: javascript, json

These are the two objects:

```
const discount = {
  rate: 0.50,
  reason: 'New Year Sales'
}

const products = [
  {
    name: 'TV',
    price: '1200'
  },
  {
    name: 'Bed',
    price: '500'
  },
  {
    name: 'Table',
    price: '50'
  }
]
```

I want to get them into a new object:

```
const newProducts = [
  {
    name: 'TV',
    price: '1200',
    rate: 0.50,
    reason: 'New Year Sales',
    finalPrice: 600
  },
  {
    name: 'Bed',
    price: '500',
    rate: 0.50,
    reason: 'New Year Sales',
    finalPrice: 250
  },
  {
    name: 'Table',
    price: '50',
    rate: 0.50,
    reason: 'New Year Sales',
    finalPrice: 25
  }
]
```

This is a JavaScript exercise and I have tried 'Object.assign' but the new value will overwrite the old ones, resulting in only the newest available. I am not sure whether destructuring using {...products} along with map, forEach will be of use. I can't make this happen

Comment: The finalPrice comes from 'rate * price' of the 2 different objects. I have no idea how to perform the calculation and creation of the object.

Comment: It sounds like that this is your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590177/merge-two-objects-without-override

Answer (score 0):

So you want to loop through each product in `products`, and apply `discount` to each one?

Use `.map` to create a new array by looping through each item in `products` and applying a callback function to it:

```
const newProducts = products.map(oldProduct=>{    
  return {
    name: oldProduct.name,
    price: oldProduct.price,
    rate: discount.rate,
    reason: discount.reason,
    finalPrice: (discount.rate * oldProduct.price)
  }
})
```

**Note:** Personally, I prefer it without destructuring, since I think it reads much more clearly. But destructuring certainly works.

Comment: Be aware this is going to mutate the original array, you could just do -> `return { rate: discount.rate, reason: discount.reason.....etc`

Comment: `I prefer it without destructuring`  The spread / destructuring is my favourite, but all 3 answers here are good.  One advantage to yours, it will work with more browsers without having to use a transpiler.  They may even be a speed advantage..

Comment: Without destructuring, this is definitely the easiest way to read it~ TQ

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map%5C), [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const discount={rate:0.50,reason:'New Year Sales'}
const products=[{name:'TV',price:'1200'},{name:'Bed',price:'500'},{name:'Table',price:'50'}]

const {rate} = discount;
const res = products.map(({price, ...rest})=>{
  return {...rest, ...discount, price, finalPrice: rate*price}
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: you sure got it right, it'll take me awhile to learn as I am still new so needed some time to digest on the destructuring part.

Comment: @ChaiChongTeh, yes it takes some time to understand, but once you understand it's easy to read and you can really make some cool working algos.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an empty object and assign the product, discount and the final price for mapping.

```js
const
    discount = { rate: 0.50, reason: 'New Year Sales' },
    products = [{ name: 'TV', price: '1200' }, { name: 'Bed', price: '500' }, { name: 'Table', price: '50' }],
    newProducts = products.map(product => Object.assign(
        {},
        product,
        discount,
        { finalPrice: product.price * (1 - discount.rate) }
    ));

console.log(newProducts);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why use `Object.assign` instead of just declaring properties on a new object?

Comment: because op wants to try with it. and i find it better than to declare new props.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with Object.assign, I'm still new to it.